# Disabling `kana/vim-textobj-entire` by filetype autocommand

Tags: autocmd, filetype, filetype-tex, plugin-vimtex, custom-text-object

`kana/vim-textobj-entire` creates text-obejcts `ae` and `ie` which stand for the entire buffer. But in `lervag/vimtex` `ae` and `ie` stand for an environment in a `.tex` file. `vimtex`'s `ae` and `ie` mappings are much more useful for `.tex` files. I wanted to disable `kana/vim-textobj-entire` for `.tex` files, so I added the following autocommand to `.vimrc`

```
augroup DisableKanaEntireForTeX
    autocmd!
    autocmd Filetype tex let g:loaded_textobj_entire=0
augroup end
```

but it's not working as expected. Although if I put `let g:loaded_textobj_entire=0` it does disable `kana/vim-textobj-entire` for all filetypes.

How can I disable a plugin's mappings for one filetype?

P.S.- Replacing `let g:loaded_textobj_entire=0` with `g:textobj_entire_no_default_key_mappings` has the same effect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**UPDATE:** Latest `vimtex` includes [PR #1711](https://github.com/lervag/vimtex/pull/1711) which allows you to configure vimtex to override existing mappings by setting this global variable from your vimrc:

```
let g:vimtex_mappings_override_existing = 1
```

So the recommended solution for this problem is update your `vimtex` to latest and include this variable setting in your vimrc.

---

**OLDER UPDATE:** It turns out `vimtex` [checks for previously existing mappings](https://github.com/lervag/vimtex/blob/34f332a223cff18c2fb41ce5a70149ff7646bb1a/autoload/vimtex.vim#L473), so it will not install one of it mappings if it finds one already exists for that key sequence.

The best workaround I can come up with is that you install these local mappings yourself, for filetype `tex`. Uninstalling `vim-textobj-entire` selectively for `tex` filetype only isn't really possible.

You can add your own mappings by creating a file `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/tex.vim` with the following contents:

```
xmap <silent><nowait><buffer> ie <plug>(vimtex-ie)
xmap <silent><nowait><buffer> ae <plug>(vimtex-ae)
omap <silent><nowait><buffer> ie <plug>(vimtex-ie)
omap <silent><nowait><buffer> ae <plug>(vimtex-ae)
```

That would ensure these mappings will get loaded for filetype `tex`, even if `vimtex` decides to skip them due to the presence of the global mappings for the same key sequences.

---

**ORIGINAL ANSWER (inaccurate):** This should *not* be necessary at all, since the mappings created by `vim-textobj-entire` are **global** mappings, while the mappings created by `vimtex` are **local** mappings, created for each buffer that triggers the `tex` (or `plaintex` etc.) filetype.

Local mappings (created with the `<buffer>` modifier to `:map` and related commands) override global ones, so the expected behavior is that the `vimtex` mappings should already supercede the key-bindings from `vim-textobj-entire`.

Regarding the part about disabling the plug-in by setting global variables, that only really work in the context of your vimrc, before the plug-in is loaded first.

If you look inside [`plugin/textobj/entire.vim`](https://github.com/kana/vim-textobj-entire/blob/master/plugin/textobj/entire.vim) from that plug-in, you'll see the first few lines are:

```
if exists('g:loaded_textobj_entire')
  finish
endif
```

So it's only checking at that point, when the plug-in is first loaded, right after the vimrc is processed. Overriding that variable later won't really have any effect, since by then this plug-in will already have been loaded and will have configured its mappings.

Comment: I reproduced the behavior described in the question with minimal `.vimrc`. `vimtex`-defined `ae` and `ie` still not working. If `vimtex` defines local mappings, I don't know why are they not working.

Comment: @MahbubAlam What does `:xmap ie` and `:omap ie` return when only one or the other plug-in are installed? In a `.tex` file? And in a different type of file?

Comment: In a `.tex` file: With `vim-textobj-entire` disabled `:xmap ie` returns `x ie @ (vimtex-ie)` (same for `:omap ie`), with `vimtex` disabled `:xmap ie` returns `x ie   (textobj-entire-i)`  (same for `:omap ie`). But with both installed `:xmap ie` returns `x ie   (textobj-entire-i)` (same for `:omap ie`).


In a different type of file: With `vim-textobj-entire` disabled `:xmap ie` returns `No mapping found` (same for `:omap ie`), with `vimtex` disabled `:xmap ie` returns `x ie   (textobj-entire-i)`  (same for `:omap ie`).

Comment: @MahbubAlam Yes you're correct! It turns out vimtex checks for existing mappings. I updated my answer, hopefully this will work for you now.

Comment: I passed your mappings through filetype autocmd `autocmd FileType tex` in `.vimrc`, now they behave expectedly for any filetype. Thanks for the mappings. Didn't know about `<silent><nowait>`. Is it better to create `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/tex.vim` and put these mappings there?

Comment: @MahbubAlam I find the ftplugin file better. But the autocmd should also work.

Comment: @kiryph submitted a PR to fix this issue, see [here](https://github.com/lervag/vimtex/pull/1709). It is merged and I think it solves the original problem posed in the question.

Comment: @KarlYngveLervåg Hmmm not sure that it will fix it, since `s:map()` is what checks whether the map already exists... Passing an extra 1 argument to the function calls should fix it though

Comment: @KarlYngveLervåg That didn't fix the problem.

Comment: Seems I was too fast. I never tested the fix myself, and I probably should have. Let's continue this discussion in the issue thread.

Comment: Update: @filbranden submitted a PR with an option to make vimtex override existing mappings on conflict. `let g:vimtex_mappings_override_existing = 1` should now specify to override existing mappings.

Comment: @KarlYngveLervåg Thank you so much! I have now updated the answer to include that as the recommended method to override existing mappings. Thanks for your very helpful and prompt code reviews!